# doseq in core.async go macro not working

Tags: asynchronous, clojure, core.async

I'm new to core.async and I'm wondering why the following does NOT work (no output at all):

```
(def jackie (chan 2))
(go (loop [food (<! jackie)]
  (if food
    (do 
      (println "Some" food "is what I was waiting for.")
      (Thread/sleep 1000)
      (recur (<! jackie))))))

(go (doseq [food ["carrots" "peas"]]
  (println "deliver" food)
  (>! jackie food)
  (Thread/sleep 1000)))
```

... while this DOES work:

```
(def jackie (chan 2))
(go (loop [food (<! jackie)]
  (if food
    (do 
      (println "Some" food "is what I was waiting for.")
      (Thread/sleep 1000)
      (recur (<! jackie))))))

(doseq [food ["carrots" "peas"]]
  (println "deliver" food)
  (>!! jackie food)
  (Thread/sleep 1000))
```

The only difference here is the missing `go` block around the last `doseq`.

I found the combined `go` and `doseq` in an example in [this blog post](https://www.laliluna.de/articles/2014/04/28/clojure-async-kindergarden-party.html), but it doesn't work for me. Also doing it the other way round and nesting the `go` inside the `doseq` like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607805/clojure-core-async-whats-the-difference-between-putting-go-block-inside) does not work for me.

Comment: Both versions work for me. How are you running the code?

Comment: In leiningen (Version: `Leiningen 2.4.1 on Java 1.6.0_65 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`) via `lein run`, Clojure is version `1.6.0` and core.async `0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

`>!!` will block the current thread if the target channel/buffer is full. To have the current go block park instead, use the single-bang variant `>!`

Comment: My mistake, I pasted the wrong code, it was supposed to be `>!` inside the `go` block, but still not working!